# GAMS CPLEX understanding the IIS report

Tags: cplex, gams-math

I am using GAMS with the CPLEX optimizer.  Within the CPLEX optimizer is an option "iis", so that it generates the irreducably inconsistent set of constraints.  If I set the iis option to 1 (or anything other than 0, I think, but I have only tested at 0 and 1), the iis equations and variables are listed.

But my problem is that this list is not given in a useful or easily consumable way.  Instead of listing the particular equation within an equation set that is part of the IIS, it will list the line in the code where this equation can be found.  But the line is generated by GAMS itself, and it is not practical or user-friendly to understand it in this form.

For instance, I am receiving an iis report that has a bunch of lines, each of which looks like this:

=E ‘upper: ‘ 445793 ‘ < 7432.83’

But I know that it is possible to have all that gibberish translated into something more user-friendly, like this:

Upper: purchase_limit(12385, 972130, t443) < 7432.83

In fact, I have even received results in such a format before.  But I cannot seem to replicate this friendlier format.

I contacted the support from GAMS, but response is slow, so I thought I'd ask this community.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Well, after 2 days of pouring through documentation and trying to get help from GAMS corp, I finally figured out the problem:

The properly labeled iis IS generated within the list file (the .lst file), but the gibberish version is ALSO generated within the list file, and it is generated near the tail end of the file, so it is easier to view.

If someone sets the iis flag and generates a list file in GAMS, be sure to grep through that file to look for something like "IIS found".  Shortly after that comment in the .lst file, you will find the list of IIS equations and variables.

I hope this helps to save time for others, or maybe at least for me in the future, when I next need this help again.